# How to effectively postion my navigation menu with css

Tags: jquery, css, html, menu, navigation

I am working on creating a new Navigation menu for my first official website and am running into an issue. When using JQuery to alter the CSS, the navigation menu shifts position. Can someone explain to me a better way to position the menu so it will absolutely stay centered, and explain the thought process? Thank you!

**CLARIFICATION- By centered I am refrencing the way the navigation menu is in the corner. I don't. Want any shimming as the padding changes on hover.

Below is my current code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#logo').mouseenter(function() {
    $('#logofade').attr("src", "csweblogoblack.png");
  });

  $('#logo').mouseleave(function() {
    $('#logofade').attr("src", "csweblogo.png");
  });

  $('.menu-item a').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css("padding-top", "30px");
    $(this).css("padding-bottom", "30px");
  });

  $('.menu-item a').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css("padding-top", "20px");
    $(this).css("padding-bottom", "20px");
  });

});
```

```css
/* color scheme: #000000 #263248 #7E8AA2 #FFFFFF #FF9800 */

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 900px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px #888888;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: -70px;
  left: -310px;
}

.menu-item a {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.logo a {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu-item a:hover {
  color: black;
}

#logo img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#logo a {
  padding: 70px 20% 10px;
  background-color: black;
}

#logo a:hover {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

#home a {
  background-color: #263248;
  padding-left: 30%;
  padding-right: 30%;
}

#contact a {
  background-color: #7E8AA2;
  padding-left: 40%;
  padding-right: 40%;
}

#about a {
  background-color: #FF9800;
  padding-left: 45%;
  padding-right: 45%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Chris Scalzi Portfolio</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <nav>
    <div class="logo" id="logo">
      <a><img id="logofade" src="csweblogo.png" alt="LOGO" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item" id="home"><a href="*">Home</a></div>
    <div class="menu-item" id="contact"><a href="*">Contact</a></div>
    <div class="menu-item" id="about"><a href="*">About</a></div>
  </nav>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using JavaScript for this?

Comment: Maybe this can help clarify your question: https://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/431e1b70dca042817dd7889a7769f8f0/

Answer (score 0):

Okay, solved the issue by changing the navigation height to 0px. not sure why this worked.... but seems to work perfectly.